# How to sort a text list of files by sizes such as as 1.0M, 2.0G and 3.5K?

Tags: shell, sorting, solaris

Here is the content of the text file:

[image]

I tried several ways but couldn't find a solution. One of them was:

```sh
cat filelist.txt | sort -nk0
```

Here is text result :
1.3M    /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/auto/Encode/JP/JP.so

1.2M    /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/auto/Encode/KR/KR.so

1.1M    /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/auto/Encode/CN/CN.so

1.0M    /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/auto/Encode/TW/TW.so

190K    /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/auto/Encode/Byte/Byte.so

138K    /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/auto/re/re.so

113K    /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/i86pc-solaris-64int/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.so

106K    /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/auto/B/B.so

106K    /usr/perl5/5.6.1/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/auto/re/re.so

104K    /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/auto/POSIX/POSIX.so

14.1K    /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/i86pc-solaris-64int/auto/DBI/DBI.so

Comment: Read documentation of [ls(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html), [stat(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html), [sort(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html), [find(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) and of [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) and [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: If you read `man sort` you will see `-h, --human-numeric-sort` which means _"compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)"_.

Comment: Sorry just to mention that I am trying to run it on Solaris server, `sort` does not have option `h` and stat does not exist and I am not using ls command , basically after I produce result I save it in a variable , and variable has these 2 strings separated by tab, and I have to sort based on 1st row.

Comment: So why did you tag your question with `linux`?

Comment: Does your version of `ls` support `-S`?

Comment: No. On Solaris 10 option `S` is not  available with `ls`

Comment: First thing you need to do is generate your file list with complete sizes if you ***really*** want the files sorted in the true order of their actual size.   Every 14K file is ***not*** the same size, but with the way you're doing this they'll be treated as having the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk to convert the sizes to bytes and then sort with -n:

```
awk '$1 ~ /M/ { $1=$1*1000000 } $1 ~ /K/ { $1=$1*1000 } $1 ~ /G/ { $1=$1*1000000000 }1' filelist.txt | sort -n
```

Comment: Didn't produce any result , did it work for you ?

Comment: Yeah, I verified that the solution worked, although it was on my local Centos 7 system.